# Conditional to compare segment_1 in the URL with the URI of a specified entry

Tags: templating, navigation, conditional

I'm trying to write a conditional that adds a class of 'here' to a navigation menu item if segment_1 of the URL matches the URI of the entry I'm specifying. But it isn't outputting anything, so I'd appreciate any help with this, thanks. Here's my code:

```
{% set about_entry = craft.entries.id(17).first() %}

<ul>
  <li {% if craft.request.getSegment(1) == '{{ about_entry.uri }}' %}class="here"{% endif %}><a href="{{ about_entry.url }}">{{ about_entry.title }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

This conditional works fine if I change '{{ about_entry.uri }}' for a hard-coded 'about', but I want the URI to be dynamic in case it gets changed in the future/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Twig you'll never, ever need to nest [logic tags](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/twig-primer#logic-tags), within [output tags](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/twig-primer#output-tags) or visa-versa.

The syntax you're looking for is:

```
{% set about_entry = craft.entries.id(17).first() %}

<ul>
    <li {% if craft.request.getSegment(1) == about_entry.uri %}class="here"{% endif %}><a href="{{ about_entry.url }}">{{ about_entry.title }}</a></li>
</ul>
```